# Cannot start Steam

Tags: release-freya, steam

I just installed elementary OS 0.3.1 Freya (64-bit). I have installed the Nvidia driver 352.55. I used [this](https://gist.github.com/jansanchez/ce5b0ca1c5e538f4b266) guide to help me install the Nvidia drivers. Afterwards I have installed Steam using

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

Everything seems fine so far. However when I try to start Steam I receive the following error:

```
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2015-11-05 19:35:42] Startup - updater built Nov 25 2013 18:07:05
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/mathyn/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/mathyn/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

So far my Google searches have not yielded a solution. Does anyone know what causes this error and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I uninstalled Steam and then used the download at the official Steam website to install. This fixed my problem.

Maybe the apt-get package is outdated?

Comment: That makes me wonder, did you run: sudo apt-get update prior to installing steam via apt-get install steam ? If not, that may have been the issue. At any rate, glad it worked out for you in the end.

Comment: I might have forgotten it, I'm not sure. I could give it another try but now that everything works I'd rather not touch it ;)

Comment: Yeah--don't fix what ain't broken lol. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Did you do a reboot after installing via
`sudo apt-get install steam` ?
I found I after I installed steam via apt-get, I had to do a reboot, then open a terminal and type `steam` . The client would open and begin updating for a couple of minutes. After updates were installed, I rebooted again and was able to click the icon to launch Steam.  All attempts to launch steam prior to reboot and running `steam` from the command line gave me errors.

Comment: Just gave it a try. Sadly it did not work for me.

Comment: @Mathyn Dang. The next thing I would try would be completely deleting steam by doing: sudo apt-get purge steam, then try to reinstall steam and reboot and run steam from the command line like my answer says. If that still doesn't work, I'll have to dig deeper.

Comment: I just found a solution. I removed Steam and used the Steam install from the official website. This worked for me. Thanks for the help!